# Unserialization of configuration schema failed, Yii2

Tags: php, html, yii, yii2

I've broken my mind..

I try to add img in HTML in Yii2.

I load it from db and put into view file, but when I try to return it in HTML tags it throw error.

But the picture is adding perfectly (checked via var_dump)

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        [
            'format' => 'html',
            'label' => 'Image',
            'value' => function($data){
                return Html::img($data->getImage(), ['width'=>200]);
            }
        ],
        'id',
        'mark',
        'model',
        'colour',
        'state_num',

        // 'price',
        // 'status',
        // 'foto:ntext',
        // 'description:ntext',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

I wanna see a picture in table. What happened with HTMLPurifier?
My img is saving as VARCHAR(255) in db.

> PHP User Error – yii\base\ErrorException
>
> Unserialization of configuration schema failed, sha1 of file was
>   da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709

Comment: if i use format 'image' it works..

Answer (score 0):

I've changed format to "raw", and it's started to work